# Tensorflow-GPU Installation ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, anaconda, conda

Ok i know this might be already answered question but i have tried almost every trick suggested on stackoverflow to install tensorflow-gpu and suggested on official docs but with no luck i am getting the same error. Firstly i have tried 
[this](https://towardsdatascience.com/setup-an-environment-for-machine-learning-and-deep-learning-with-anaconda-in-windows-5d7134a3db10) then afterwards offical docs then stackoverflow tricks but still getting error I have installed

1. Anaconda 3.5 which was with python 3.7 but then i downgraded it to 3.6.6
2. Then created virtual env named tensorflow with python 3.6.6
3. Then in tensorflow env pip install tensorflow-gpu
4. It was installed successfully then i installed CUDA 9.0
5. Then cuDNN 7.3 for CUDA 9.0(I have also tried CUDA 8.0 with cuDNN 6.1)
6. Copied all DLL cuDNN bin/lib to CUDA 9.0 bin/lib
7. Specified CUDA system environment variable path upto bin

   **SAME QUESTION IS ASKED [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52697809/import-tensorflow-as-tf-gives-errors-even-after-installing-without-errors) BUT HAS NO ANSWER I HAVE THE SAME TRACE.**

   Python 3.6.6 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Jun 28 2018, 11:27:44) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
   Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

   > > > import tensorflow
   > > >       Traceback (most recent call last):
   > > >       File "D:\conda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in 
   > > >       from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
   > > >       File "D:\conda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 29, in 
   > > >       _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
   > > >       File "D:\conda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 25, in swig_import_helper
   > > >       _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
   > > >       File "D:\conda\envs\tensorflow\lib\imp.py", line 243, in load_module
   > > >       return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
   > > >       File "D:\conda\envs\tensorflow\lib\imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
   > > >       return _load(spec)
   > > >       ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
  File "D:\conda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow__init__.py", line 22, in 
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
  File "D:\conda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python__init__.py", line 49, in 
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "D:\conda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 74, in 
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\conda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in 
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "D:\conda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 29, in 
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "D:\conda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 25, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "D:\conda\envs\tensorflow\lib\imp.py", line 243, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "D:\conda\envs\tensorflow\lib\imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources#common_installation_problems

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.

Please help me to get out of this.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem with you. After try many things, I can solved the problem with these processes.

1.Created virtual environment named tensorflow with python 3.5

- conda create -n tensorflow pip python-3.5

2.Activate this environment and install tensorflow

- activate tensorflow
- pip install --ignore-installed --upgrade tensorflow-gpu

For CUDA, after installed CUDA 9.0, I create new folder in drive C and copy cuDNN 7.3 for CUDA 9.0 to its. Then, specified CUDA system environment variable path (bin folder).

In my case:  C:\tools\cuda\bin

Hope this can help you :)