# Tensorflow : ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found

Tags: python, tensorflow

I started a python machine learning video series and I have trouble with the first video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ujTCoH21GlA&list=PLzMcBGfZo4-mP7qA9cagf68V06sko5otr&index=2&t=0s where the set up is explained. I installed anaconda and pycharm, and followed all the steps to install tensorflow and keras. When I do everything like in the video I have an error message when trying to run the code "import tensorflow" (without the quotes).

With this interpreter : C:\Users\Sam\Anaconda3\envs\tensor\pythonw.exe
I get the following error message : ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found

I tried to tweak everything to find the origin of the error and I managed to get the code running with no error with this interpreter : C:\Users\Sam\Anaconda3\python.exe
But it does not work with import keras, I get the same error as above. I tried with python 3.6 and 3.7 and there is no difference. I tried downgrading tensorflow to 1.1 but it did not work either.

I think I do a mistake when it comes to Pycharm because I tried in the anaconda console and import tensorflow works perfectly... If you have any idea how to fix this please let me know, 
I looked online and on stackoverflow but most of the solutions are for GPU installation and the few for CPU did not work for me.

Cheers !

Comment: Hi, and welcome to StackOverflow. If you're getting the error in PyCharm but not Anaconda, then you should go to your PyCharm console and pip install tensorflow.

Comment: I sometimes find that even when in an conda enviroment, pip install will install stuff to the base environment. You can run `where pip` to see which pip you are using. I think the top one is the one used by default. If you want you can copy to full path 
 and doe something like this: `C:// ..../pip.exe install keras`

Comment: Thank you both for the answer. I tried installing tensorflow in the pycharm console but it said that it was already installed, but it did not fix the problem. @erncyp you used a lingo too advanced for me I'm not sure I understood everything. I typed where pip and it returned me this : C:\Users\Sam\Anaconda3\Scripts\pip.exe I am not sure what the top pip is, and what do you mean by copy to full path ? I think it might be close to what I am looking for, Cheers

Comment: Can you please try answers from these  similar issues  .   https://stackoverflow.com/a/43959499/11530462                            https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53090359/tensorflow-gpu-installation-importerror-dll-load-failed-the-specified-module-c